Ensuring Order of Package Installation with Conda to Enable CUDA with PyTorch
I am attempting to streamline the setup of a Python environment that leverages both CUDA and PyTorch through Conda. My goal is to craft a unified environment.yml file that concurrently installs CUDA and a CUDA-capable version of PyTorch. However, I've encountered an issue where the installation order by Conda leads to PyTorch defaulting to a CPU-only version, seemingly because it installs PyTorch prior to CUDA, missing the CUDA availability during its setup.
Objective: Craft an environment.yml for Conda that guarantees the installation of CUDA before PyTorch to ensure the latter can leverage GPU capabilities.
Problem: Conda's installation order occasionally prioritizes PyTorch before CUDA. As a result, PyTorch does not recognize the presence of CUDA on the system and reverts to a CPU-only installation.
Key Question: Is there a methodology or a specific configuration within Conda that enforces the installation of CUDA before PyTorch to circumvent this issue?
Below is a minimal representation of my environment.yml file that illustrates the problem:
# environment.yml
name: notworking
dependencies:
  - nvidia/label/cuda-12.1.0::cuda
  - python=3.11
  - pytorch::pytorch
  - pytorch::pytorch-cuda=12.1
  - pytorch::torchaudio
  - pytorch::torchvision 

While relocating the pytorch dependencies to a pip section within the YAML file addresses this immediate challenge, it does not provide a scalable solution for future scenarios where similar sequence-dependency issues may arise with packages lacking pip installers.
Additional Context:
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04
Conda Version: 23.3.1
Hardware: NVIDIA RTX 3060


What is the motivation behind installing nvidia/label/cuda-12.1.0::cuda?

@Ivan cuda 12.1 is the latest version (expressly) supported by Pytorch.(see https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally).

You don't need to install the CUDA package as it comes with pytorch-cuda.
